# Android WebView animate to fullscreen

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen, stretch, android-fullscreen

I have a small webview as part of the screen layout, together with many other views (buttons, images, etc.).

When the user taps the webview, I'm trying to animate it to fullscreen (or just stretch it without animation).

The problem is, if the webview is a part of, for example, a relative layout, and its position is defined relative to its siblings (e.g. layout_toRightOf) then those limitations continue to hold, and the webview is only stretched accordingly. Is there a workaround to this problem? Can the webview somehow be temporarily extracted and put "on top of everything else on the screen"?

P.S. the url inside the webview must not be reloaded in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout params

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
webview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Add the webview to the layout and then set the content view with the new layout.